# Is it possible to implement the spread operator on other classes?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to implement the spread operator on other classes in the same way you can with other operators like `+`, for example:

```
class Demo{
  operator fun plus(i:Int):Demo {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the one we use for varargs? Operator overloading is documented here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can`t. The spread operator is not matched by any function therefore it can not be overloaded in Kotlin.

When looking at the bytecode created by the compiler one can see, that `vararg` is compiled to an array. The spread operator just creates a copy of that array.

For example:

```
fun test(vararg strings: String) {
}

fun main() {
    val params = arrayOf("1", "2")
    test(*params)
}
```

compiles to:

```
INVOKESTATIC java/util/Arrays.copyOf ([Ljava/lang/Object;I)[Ljava/lang/Object;
CHECKCAST [Ljava/lang/String;
INVOKESTATIC CoroutineTestKt.test ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
```